# I Cannot Change the Font or Paper Size for the TikZPoster Document Class

Tags: fontsize, paper-size, tikzposter

For some reason, it doesn't let me change the font size or paper size for the `tikzposter` document class. These two lines give the exact same output:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper]{tikzposter}
```

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{tikzposter}
```

Either way, the paper size is way too huge and the text size is way too small.
I am compiling fith PDFLateX.

Here is the full source code and document:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper]{tikzposter}

\title{Glasses for Hyperopia}
\author{Amar Al-Zubaidi}
\institute{institute}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{~}
{
   \begin{itemize}
       \item Hyperopia is commonly known as far-sightedness. 
   \end{itemize}
}

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.4}
    \block{Treatments}{Text and more text}
    
    \column{0.6}
    \block{Diagram}{Here, \blindtext \vspace{4cm}}
    \note[
        targetoffsetx=-9cm, 
        targetoffsety=-6.5cm, 
        width=0.5\linewidth
        ]
        {e-mail \texttt{welcome@overleaf.com}}
\end{columns}

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.5}
    \block{Explanation}
    {
        \begin{tikzfigure}
        \end{tikzfigure}
    }
    \column{0.5}
    \block{Description of the figure}{\blindtext}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no such options in `tikzposter`  class. The smallest paper size is a2paper.  The smallest font size is 12pt. https://muug.ca/mirror/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzposter/tikzposter.pdf

Comment: As I mentioned in the [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/va9ri4/i_cannot_change_the_font_or_paper_size_for_the/) on the same topic by the same poster, the geometry package is loaded and its capabilities can be used directly to set the page size, e.g., `\geometry{papersize={34in,24in}}`.

Comment: Thanks, I used 12pt and a2paper.